# DTS task failed, DTS-077100: Record Replicator error in table asyncprocess.outgoing_bot. cause by jdbc Operation failed

Tags: sql-server, synchronization, migration, alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-rds

I'm doing real-time replication between two SQL Server using Data Transmission Service (DTS) which provided by Alibaba Cloud. And after the full data migration completed, the task was suspended during incremental data migration.

Then I checked task details, it says:

"DTS task failed
Region: Malaysia (Kuala Lumpur)

Task ID/Name: dts-task-id-string / dts-task-name

> DTS-077100: Record Replicator error in table asyncprocess.outgoing bot. cause by
> [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:Operationfailed.Theindexentryof
> length 1910 bytes for the index ' WA Sys 00000004 3D2915A8' exceeds the maximum
> length of 1700 bytes for nonclustered indexes.]

Also, I refer the related document as below, nothing found similar to my case.
https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/solving-the-dts-077100-error-during-data-synchronization_598444

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, the error message is also displayed. Let me just delete the image as that may cause misunderstanding.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this case, the structure of the table mentioned in the output may not meet the requirements. Check data schema, be sure the table has primary key or at least has a unique non-null index.

Reference:
https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/34357.htm

[All prerequisites for SQL Server incremental migration using DTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alsSC.png)

Comment: Again - posting images is highly discouraged. It is odd that you solved your problem in less than 10 minutes after posting. A helpful answer would identify what actually caused your error and what specific steps you took to solve it.

Comment: Many appreciate. actually I got this error long ago, and it did cost a while to figure out. Why I post this is just because I received the same question from someone else, and meanwhile I thought there might be other people encountered the similar problem waiting for help.